# Why Does ShowDialog Crash in MonoDevelop?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, monodevelop

I have a trouble building and running my working C# project under MonoDevelop.

Any call of `OpenFileDilog.ShowDialog()` shows me a window with a proper title, but completely blanc. The executive waits for a while and than crashes.

I also have another C# project build in the same MonoDevelop enviroment, that works fine. Well, not that fine, but at least OpenFileDialogs doesn't lead to crash. So I'm a little bit puzzled here. Can it be project specific? What should I do to avoid it?

**Upddate:** It works the same way with any modal form. So It's not `OpenFileDilog`, it's `ShowDialog()`. And it might have something to do with some other windows open by ShowDialog caller.

So. I have a form, which opens some other forms with `Show()`, and then tries to open another window with `ShowDialog()` - and goes then as descibed above.

Some details:

*Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K594)*

*Mono 2.10.6*

*MonoDevelop 2.8.5*

Comment: Have you compared references between the two projects?

Comment: Are you passing in a valid InitialDirectory?

Comment: It would help to know what OS you're using and the versions of Mono and MonoDevelop.

Comment: I don't specify InitialDirectory at all. Should I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm, settings `FormBorderStyle` to `System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow` generates a crash in Mono in some situations (here when I open a `MessageBox` from a dialog that has `FixedToolWindow`).

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug in Mono. My other non modal windows had `FormBorderStyle` set to `FixedToolWindow`. As soon as I set it back to `Sizable`, everything works normal.